# Visualize transformation when reprojecting from Mercator to equirectangular

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, python-3, animation, transform

I am trying to visualize the map distortion that occurs when reprojecting from Mercator to equirectangular coordinate systems. The actual reprojection is not difficult, but I want to save images (preferably .PNG files) of the transformation process to visualize the distortion that is occurring during the transformation. I need at least 48 sequential frames to do an animation.

I would prefer to use Python to do the reprojection.

I was thinking I could use a callback with gdal.warp(), but I could only find progress bar examples with the callback option, and am unsure how to save a raster file with each iteration instead of doing a progress bar.

So something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal

def save_image(complete, message, data):
    # Save the image to PNG file.
    # How to save the image? Is there an attribute I can use?

options = {
            "callback": save_image, 
            "dstSRS": "EPSG:4326", 
            "srcSRS": "EPSG:3857"
}

gdal.Warp(dst, src, gdal.WarpOptions(**options))
```

Here is the starting image in case anyone needs it:

[image: Starting Image]